# Importing operators with RXJS 5.0.0-beta.6 and Angular 2 RC1

Tags: angular, rxjs, systemjs

I am building an Angular 2 web app using Typescript and am trying to switch from Angular2-beta-17 to Angular2-RC1. I am struggling to get the imports of the RXJS operators to work. I am using SystemJS as a module loader, and suspect this is were the problem lies.

I copy the file bundles I need from my node modules to a lib-folder and then include the files in the index.html file like this (the commented sections are some of the many combinations of different attempts for solutions I have tried):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Workout Player</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> -->

    <script src="lib/es6-shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/Rx.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/zone.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/core.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/common.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/http.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/compiler.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/crypto-js.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular2-jwt.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="lib/shims_for_IE.js"></script>    -->
    <!-- <script src="lib/angular2-polyfills.js"></script> -->

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({ 
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js',
          },
        // 'rxjs'                             : {main: 'Rx.umd.js'},
        // '@angular/core'                    : {main: 'core.umd.js'},
        // '@angular/common'                  : {main: 'common.umd.js'},
        // '@angular/compiler'                : {main: 'compiler.umd.js'},
        // '@angular/router'                  : {main: 'router.umd.js'},
        // '@angular/platform-browser'        : {main: 'platform-browser.umd.js'},
        // '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {main: 'platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js'}
        },
        map: {
          'crypto-js': 'lib/crypto-js.js',
          'angular2-jwt': 'lib/angular2-jwt.js',
          'rxjs': 'lib',
          // 'rxjs/*': 'lib',  
          // 'rxjs/add/operator/*': 'lib/Rx.umd.js',
          '@angular/core'                    : 'lib',
          '@angular/common'                  : 'lib',
          '@angular/http'                    : 'lib',
          '@angular/compiler'                : 'lib',
          '@angular/platform-browser'        : 'lib',
          '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'lib'
        },
        // paths: {
        //         'rxjs/observable/*' : 'lib/Rx.umd.js',
        //         'rxjs/operator/*' : 'lib/Rx.umd.js',
        //         'rxjs/*' : 'lib/Rx.umd.js'
        //     }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

    <style>body { width:100%;}</style>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <workout-player>Loading...</workout-player>
  </body>
</html>
```

The imports of the operators are done like this:

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import {JwtHelper} from 'angular2-jwt';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
import {LocalStorageService} from '../storage/local-storage.service';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
/**
 * Service class for handling login
 */
export class LoginService {...
```

I had no problem with this in Angular2-beta17 when using the angular2-dev.js bundle file. The errors I am now getting in the developers console in Chrome:
[image: Errors in developers console in Chrome]

The browser should not try to get these resources at all. I am quite new with both Angular and SystemJS so I'm sorry if im missing something trivial here.

Comment: If you're using systemJS, you shouldn't be loading all those scripts directly like that. See [the quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) - you just need to load a couple of shims and let systemJS do the rest

Comment: Thank you, I was using systemJS wrong and have started to read up on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't define Rxjs into a packages block as well. So SystemJS doesn't append a default extension to module names.

See this configuration taken from the 5 min quickstart (see https://angular.io/guide/quickstart):

```
var packages = {
  'app': { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }, // <----------
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
};

var packageNames = [
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/router-deprecated',
  '@angular/testing',
  '@angular/upgrade',
];

packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
  packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Thierry! I followed the 5 min quickstart a few months ago, but it had changed a lot, which I had not noticed. I used package blocks and default extension and got it working. I also stopped copying files to a lib folder, which I only did to try to prepare for a "distribution" build of the Single Page App i'm building, but I will focus on developing and worry about distribution later :-)