# Issue with chaining a number of RxJS Observable operators

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I am trying to find the cleanest solution and operators in order to chain observables.

My requirements are as follows:

1. Retrieve a `userAccountToken` from route params
2. Use that `userAcccountToken` in order to do a http call to the backend
3. Again use the `userAcccountToken` in order to do another http call to the backend
4. Finally navigate to a route (i.e. `/dashboard`) if all has gone well above.

My angular 2 component is as follows:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {UserAccountService} from '../useraccount.service';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {SessionService} from '../../session/session.service';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'useraccount-activation.component.html'
})
export class UserAccountActivationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userAccountService: UserAccountService,
              private sessionService: SessionService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.map(params => params['userAccountToken'])//1.
      .switchMap(userAccountToken => this.userAccountService.activateAccount(userAccountToken))//2.
      .switchMap(() => this.sessionService.signinByUserAccountToken('???'))//3.
      .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']));//4.
  }
}
```

The issue is that I need the `userAccountToken` in two places and yet I need to subscribe to both http calls so that they are executed.

I could perform another `this.route.params.map(...)` between 2. and 3. but that seems repeating myself.

I could introduce state in the component with a `userAccountToken` instance variable but then my functions would be creating side-effects.

What could be a clean solution to this problem?

**edit**: The following code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.map(params => params['userAccountToken'])
      .mergeMap(userAccountToken => Observable.concatAll(
        this.userAccountService.activateAccount(userAccountToken),
        this.sessionService.signinByUserAccountToken(userAccountToken)
      ))
      .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']));
  }
```

yields the following error:

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.concatAll is not a function
```

even though I have imported `import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatAll';`

**edit 2**: The reason I get the above error is that I use `concatAll` on `Observable` and not on a instance/object of type `Observable`...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`forkJoin`](http://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) assuming both backend calls can be done in parallel. If you have to do it on after another you can use nested [`mergeMap`](http://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html).

```js
const token$ = Rx.Observable.of('token')

token$
  .mergeMap(token => Rx.Observable.forkJoin(
    Rx.Observable.of(token),
    Rx.Observable.of(token)
  ))
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

*Side Note:* You should really export this functionality into a service ;)

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Could you please provide a sample of how my `ngOnInit ` would look like please?

Comment: Added an executable example that shows how to make use of forkJoin.

Comment: Thanks. I actually need `concatAll` because one http call needs to be issued before the other one. I will update my code. Bear with me.

Comment: I have edited my question. I am having issues importing the `concatAll` operator... Can you please explain how to get this to work in the context of angular2?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your initial question. Please be so kind and ask a new question and close/accept this one. Note that the import depends also on the Rx version you're using.

Comment: Umm. I do believe it is related to my question. You see `concatAll` is a prototype method on Observable so has to be used on an object/instance and I am not sure how to do that in the context of my question. Can you please edit your answer to explain how to use `concatAll` in the context of my original question? Bottom line: this is not an import issue...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176025/importing-operators-with-rxjs-5-0-0-beta-6-and-angular-2-rc1

Comment: You said in your comment that you have issues importing `concatAll` so I thought this is you issue. I updated my answer, b/c I think I misread the documentation about `concatAll`.

Comment: Try a nested `mergeMap` (as I mentioed in my answer) or if you want no nesting use `mapTo` to pass along the token instead of the HTTP result.